# Why does nuget consider 1.2.3.4 to be a stable (release) version?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, semantic-versioning

I'm seeing below:

```
1.2.3          // release
1.2.3+hash     // release
1.2.3-alpha    // pre-release
1.2.3-alpha.12 // pre-release

1.2.3.4        // why is this release version and not pre-release version or invalid?
1.2.3.4.5      // invalid nuget version
```

I don't see why `1.2.3.4` is considered as a release version mentioned anywhere below:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning
- https://semver.org/

Comment: The short answer is that Microsoft wanted to adopt SemVer while at the same time maintaining backward compatibility with their 4-part versioning scheme, where even release versions can have 4 parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What is the definition of a pre-release version?

NuGet (mostly) conforms to SemVer2, as defined on their website: https://semver.org/

Section 9 starts: https://semver.org/#spec-item-9

> A pre-release version MAY be denoted by appending a hyphen and a series of dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch version

### But SemVer2 doesn't allow 4 segment versions

Correct, but as [Joe Sewell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137382/joe-sewell) mentioned in the question's comment, NuGet was adding backwards compatibility support for what it previously supported. In fact, here's the commit that added SemVer support into NuGet, back in 2011: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/commit/a999416414071f321f1ad5aa6d8c744ba0715e3a

We can see from numerous files that NuGet was previously using `System.Version` as the package version before this, and you can see from [`System.Version`'s docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netcore-3.1) that it contains this 4 segment version. The very first version of `SemVer.cs` contained [the comment](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/commit/a999416414071f321f1ad5aa6d8c744ba0715e3a#diff-a8b7ef60a83b54b06cfc0d3420a97cc435876679da1eb15ac2fe49f7551bc276R10-R11):

> A hybrid implementation of SemVer that supports semantic versioning as described at http://semver.org while not strictly enforcing it to
> allow older 4-digit versioning schemes to continue working.

The file was later renamed to `SemanticVersion`, and later split into a `NuGetVersion`, extending a strictly-semver2 `SemanticVersion`, but [this comment still exists to this day](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/1dd5351295a5a0d092abcd2bd82ccbd730682dbe/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Versioning/NuGetVersion.cs#L10-L12).

### Conclusion

So, while SemVer2's definition of pre-release explicitly requires the hyphen to immediately follow  the patch version, backwards compatibility prevented NuGet, even as young as 1 year after initial release, from moving exclusively to strict SemVer2 compliance.

Therefore, some reinterpretation of SemVer2 was needed, and the choice was to make the hyphen the pre-release signal, not having more than 3 segments. 9 years later this is what we have, and there are thousands of packages on nuget.org using 4 segment versions, some with additional prerelease labels.